# Every time I type elif in code it shows error when I start program

Tags: python

Every time I type `elif` in code it shows error when I start program

```
# This is game creating practice
import random
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)
print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

# Ask the player to guess 6 times
for guessesTaken in range(1, 7):
    print('Take a guess.')
    guess = int(input())

    if guess < secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
        elif guess > secretNumber:
            print('Your guess is to high.')
        else:
            break  # This condition is the correct guess!

if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Good job! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses!)
else:
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))
```

Comment: Help you do what? You've not asked a question

Comment: This is a question and answer site, not a coding tutorial service.

Comment: *What errors???* But the answer is because your elif is not on the right indentation level.

Comment: Check the indentation on your `elif` and `else` statements.  Also make sure you close the string after `guesses!`.  Closing due to a simple typo.

Comment: If your code gives you an error, you should mention it here. Copy and paste the whole error

Comment: align your elif statements with your if statement.  The spacing is off.

Comment: If you get an error you should be telling us what the error is.

Comment: You are missing a quote on `' guesses!)` as well

Comment: You need to align your `elif` statements with the `if` statement. You also have an unclosed string literal on the 3rd line from the bottomthat will cause errors.

Comment: it says: 'Syntax error : invalid syntax '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, whitespace is important.

Your `elif` should be on the same column as your `if`.

Comment: The `else` statement is also affected and don't forget about closing the string literal near the end of the code.